# Pandas how to calculate the std deviation for all label values except for the selected label?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have a DF with labels and values as below:

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'labels' : ['A','A', 'B', 'C', 'C'],'val' : [1, 2, 3, 4, 5]})
```

Now, I want to calculate the std. dev as below:

for each row:

row with A: (std dev of B and C labels) (first 2 rows would have std dev of all other rows)

row with B: (std dev of A and C labels) (third row would have std dev of all other rows)

row with C: (std dev of A and B labels) (last 2 rows would have std dev of all other rows)

How can I achieve this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Update**
To optimise, precompute std dev for each label:

```py
df = pd.DataFrame({'labels' : ['A','A', 'B', 'C', 'C'],'val' : [1, 2, 3, 4, 5]})

labels = df.labels.unique()

std_map = {l:df[df.labels != l]["val"].std() for l in labels}

df["std_dev"] = df["labels"].apply(lambda l: std_map[l])
```

---

Iterate dataframe and filter rows with other labels and compute std dev:

```py
df = pd.DataFrame({'labels' : ['A','A', 'B', 'C', 'C'],'val' : [1, 2, 3, 4, 5]})

df["std_dev"] = df.apply(lambda row: df[df.labels != row["labels"]]["val"].std(), axis=1)

[Out]:
  labels  val   std_dev
0      A    1  1.000000
1      A    2  1.000000
2      B    3  1.825742
3      C    4  1.000000
4      C    5  1.000000
```

Comment: @Aditya, since there is no expected output in the question, it is difficult to verify the output generated above.

Comment: Thank  you, the std. dev is correct but it takes a lot of time to calculate for a large dataset..

Comment: @Aditya, updated answer with optimisation.

Comment: @AzharKhan Does finding the unique label reduce the time ??

Comment: @rootExplorr, it is relatively better than previous solution as it does not compute the results for the duplicate entries.